# Errors while debugging code using HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath

Tags: apache, perl, lwp-useragent

I am getting some errors when I try to debug the following code.

Note that it fetches the data from approx 6,000 fields from the `http://europa.eu/youth/volunteering/evs-organisation#open`

After parsing each page, check for the existence of the `next ›` link at the bottom.

View-source is a browser based command. It tells the browser to output the response in plain text rather than render it based on its actual content type, HTML in this case. You should not need to include view-source in your URL.

Here we have a script that extracts the data out of each block and cleans it up a little. The `browse` function is generic. It takes an input reference which contains the URL and XPaths of the parent and children in order to construct the output ref. It is just  an approach: it does not yet navigate across each page,

In a rough script I tested, I fetched the total results using `//span[@class="ey_badge"]` then the max page using

```
my $page_max = $results / 21;
$page_max    = int( $page_max ) == $page_max ? $page_max-- : int( $page_max ) ;
```

See the errors

```
martin@linux-3645:~/dev/perl> perl eu.pl
syntax error at eu.pl line 81, near "our "
Global symbol "$iterator_organizations" requires explicit package name at eu.pl line 81.
Can't use global @_ in "my" at eu.pl line 84, near "= @_"
Missing right curly or square bracket at eu.pl line 197, at end of line
Execution of eu.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
martin@linux-3645:~/dev/perl> ^C
martin@linux-3645:~/dev/perl>
```

It fetches the data from approx 6,000 fields from `http://europa.eu/youth/volunteering/evs-organisation#open`

See the code

```perl
use strict;  
use warnings FATAL => qw#all#;

use LWP::UserAgent;  
use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath;  
use Data::Dumper;  

my $handler_relurl      = sub { q#https://europa.eu# . $_[0] };  
my $handler_trim        = sub { $_[0] =~ s#^\s*(.+?)\s*$#$1#r };  
my $handler_val         = sub { $_[0] =~ s#^[^:]+:\s*##r };  
my $handler_split       = sub { [ split $_[0], $_[1] ] };  
my $handler_split_colon = sub { $handler_split->( qr#; #, $_[0] ) };  
my $handler_split_comma = sub { $handler_split->( qr#, #, $_[0] ) };  

my $conf = {  
    url      => q#https://europa.eu/youth/volunteering/evs-organisation_en#,  
    parent   => q#//div[@class="vp ey_block block-is-flex"]#,  
    children => {  
        internal_url => [ q#//a/@href#, [ $handler_relurl ] ],  
        external_url => [ q#//i[@class="fa fa-external-link fa-lg"]/parent::p//a/@href#, [ $handler_trim ] ],  
        title        => [ q#//h4# ],  
        topics       => [ q#//div[@class="org_cord"]#, [ $handler_val, $handler_split_colon ] ],  
        location     => [ q#//i[@class="fa fa-location-arrow fa-lg"]/parent::p#, [ $handler_trim ] ],  
        hand         => [ q#//i[@class="fa fa-hand-o-right fa-lg"]/parent::p#, [ $handler_trim, $handler_split_comma ] ],  
        pic_number   => [ q#//p[contains(.,'PIC no')]#, [ $handler_val ] ],  
    }  
};  

print Dumper browse( $conf );  

sub browse {  
    my $conf = shift;  

    my $ref = [ ];  

    my $lwp_useragent = LWP::UserAgent->new( agent => q#IE 6#, timeout => 10 );  
    my $response      = $lwp_useragent->get( $conf->{url} );  
    die $response->status_line unless $response->is_success;  
    my $content       = $response->decoded_content;  

    my $html_treebuilder_xpath = HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new_from_content( $content );  
    my @nodes = $html_treebuilder_xpath->findnodes( $conf->{parent} );

    for my $node ( @nodes ) {  
        push @$ref, { };   

        while ( my ( $key, $val ) = each %{ $conf->{children} } ) {  
            my $xpath    = $val->[0];  
            my $handlers = $val->[1] // [ ];  

            $val = ( $node->findvalues( qq#.$xpath# ) )[0] // next;  
            $val = $_->( $val ) for @$handlers;  
            $ref->[-1]->{$key} = $val;  
        }  
    }  

    return $ref;  
} 

{  
    'internal_url' => 'https://europa.eu/youth/volunteering/organisation/948417016_en',  
    'external_url' => 'http://www.apd.ge',  
    'location'     => 'Tbilisi, Georgia',  
    'title'        => '"Academy for Peace and Development" Union',  
    'topics'       => [  
        'Access for disadvantaged',  
        'Youth (Participation, Youth Work, Youth Policy)',  
        'Intercultural/intergenerational education and (lifelong)learning'  
    ],  
    'pic_number'   => '948417016',  
    'hand'         => [  
        'Receiving',  
        'Sending'  
    ]  
} 

our $iterator_organizations = sub {  
    my ( $browser, $parent ) = @_;  

    my $url = q#https://europa.eu/youth/volunteering/evs-organisation_en#;  

    my $nodes = $browser->nodes( url => $url );  

    my $iterator = sub {  
        return shift @$nodes;  
    };  

    return ( $iterator, 1 );  


our $iterator_organizations_b = sub {  
    my ( $browser, $parent ) = @_;  

    my $url   = q#https://europa.eu/youth/volunteering/evs-organisation_en#;  
    my $uri   = URI->new( $url );  
    my $xpath = q#//div[@class="vp ey_block block-is-flex"]#;  
    my $nodes = [ ];  
    my $page  = 0;  

    my $results  = $parent->{results};  
    my $page_max = $results / 21;  
    $page_max    = int($page_max) == $page_max ? $page_max-- : int($page_max);  

    my $iterator_uri = sub {  
        $uri->query_form( page => $page++ );  

        return $page > 2 ? undef : $uri ; # $page_max;  
    };  

    my $iterator_node = sub {

        unless ( @$nodes ) {

            my $uri = $iterator_uri->( ) // return undef;  

            my $options = $page == 1 ? { tree => $parent->{_node} } : { url => $uri->as_string };  

            $nodes = $browser->nodes( %$options, xpath => $xpath );  
        }  

        return shift @$nodes;  
    };  

    return ( $iterator_node, 0 );  
};  

our $iterator_organization = sub {  
    my ( $browser, $parent ) = @_;  

    my $url = $parent->{internal_url};  

    my $nodes = $browser->nodes( url => $url );  

    my $iterator = sub {  
        return shift @$nodes;  
    };  

    return ( $iterator, 1 );  
};  


sub organizations {  
    my ( $self, $options ) = ( shift, { @_ } );  

    my $map = [  
        $Massweb::Browser::Europa::iterator_organizations,  
        results       => q#.//span[@class="ey_badge"]#,  
        organizations => [  
            $Massweb::Browser::Europa::iterator_organizations_b,  
            internal_url => [ q#.//a/@href#, $Massweb::Browser::Europa::handler_url ],  
            external_url => [ q#.//i[@class="fa fa-external-link fa-lg"]/parent::p//a/@href#, $Massweb::Browser::handler_trim ],  
            title        => q#.//h4#,  
            topics       => [ q#.//div[@class="org_cord"]#, $Massweb::Browser::handler_val, $Massweb::Browser::handler_list_colon ],  
            location     => [ q#.//i[@class="fa fa-location-arrow fa-lg"]/parent::p#, $Massweb::Browser::handler_trim ],  
            hand         => [ q#.//i[@class="fa fa-hand-o-right fa-lg"]/parent::p#, $Massweb::Browser::handler_trim, $Massweb::Browser::handler_list_comma ],  
            pic_number   => [ q#.//p[contains(.,'PIC no')]#, $Massweb::Browser::handler_val ],  
            recruiting   => [ q#boolean(.//i[@class="fa fa-user-times fa-lg"])#, $Massweb::Browser::handler_bool_rev ],  
            _            => \&organization,  
        ],  
    ];  

    my $organizations = $self->browse( map => $map );  

    return $organizations;  
}  

sub organization {  
    my ( $self, $options ) = ( shift, { @_ } );  

    my $map = [  
        sub { $Massweb::Browser::Europa::iterator_organization->( $_[0], $options ) },  
       #title       => q#.//h1#,  
        description => q#.//div[@class="ey_vp_detail_page"]/p#,  
    ];  

    my $organization = $self->browse( map => $map );  

    return $organization;  
}
```

Comment: Yóur `$page_max    = int( $page_max ) == $page_max ? $page_max-- : int( $page_max )` is strange. It says, "if the variable is an integer then decrement it and then reassign its original value, otherwise remove its fractional part.

Comment: Hello dear Borodin - many thanks for the hint: well- since i am a perl-beginner i try to learn here. I think that i need to rework the code and have to make it more simple -

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be the block/anonymous hash starting `'internal_url'`. I can't imagine what you intend there but it is a syntax error and would have no effect if you fixed it

Why are you declaring so many subroutine references like `our $iterator_organizations = sub { ... }` instead of using standard subroutines? It is a very strange approach

Comment: hello dear Borodin, many thanks for the hints. This is very valuable. I am glad. Note: i want to fetch the data from the site http://europa.eu/youth/volunteering/evs-organisation#open
Note - it is just a simple approach to fetches the data from approx 6,000 fields - i am just a beginner in Perl...